# MySQL Workbench Root Password

Tags: mysql, passwords, root

Just had helpdesk install mySQL Workbench but when trying to connect to a new connection i am asked for a root password. I try to connect without putting in the password but am thrown an error.

Comment: Then ask helpdesk what the username and password is. There is no way we can tell you what combination you should use.

Answer (score 0):

After research i found that whoever installs your mySQL will set up the root password. i eventually got the password from help desk